# Blank Attribute Values in wso2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 IS 4.5.0. I recently modified the standard policy editor so as to use a new attribute but the modification doesn't seem to work. Specifically, when I select the attribute and hit Search, the attribute finder returns the message:

> No entitlement data finder module is defined for this category

Has anyone an idea on how to resolve this? thanks in advance, 
Maria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.... It is the expected behavior with default implementation. Let me explain this further; Attributes are retrieved to this UI page, using an pluggable entitlement data finder modules. These modules can be plugged with WSO2IS. Attribute sources can be from databases, user stores or any... Default implementation is only retrieved roles from WSO2IS user store. But, if you want more to show in this UI, You can do it by extending default implementations. Please find the source fore default implementation from [here](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/entitlement/pap/CarbonEntitlementDataFinder.java). This would help you to get some idea.

Comment: Thank you Asela! I really appreciate your help. Since I am a newbie in wso2, is there any point of reference/example to understand better the modifications that are needed? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi again! I managed to edit the CarbonEntitlementDataFinder.java and recompiled the corresponding package with maven. Then I replaced the corresponding .jar to plugins directory. Finally i restarted the server but no change was made. The same message is issued. Does anyone have an idea about this??? Thank you.

Comment: I can not say exactly.. Normally jar replacing is enough.. I suggest you to debug the your "CarbonEntitlementDataFinder" class and see...  You can debug... by   starting server as  ">wso2carbon.sh --debug 5005"

Comment: Hi again! Just a small clarification. After modifying the CarbonEntitlementDataFinder.java, i recompiled the \source\components\identity\org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement\4.2.0 and then i replaced the org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement_4.2.0.jar in \wso2is-4.5.0\repository\components\plugins directory. Did i need to do anything further (ex. recompilation of kernel etc.) or anything else? Thank you!